# What is the correct way to implement a stack in Go so that it will store structs?

Tags: types, go, stack

I'm trying to make a stack that will store a series of Huffman Tree structs. Currently I'm using an implementation that I found on github.

```
package util

type item struct {
    value interface{}
    next  *item
}

//Stack the implementation of stack
//this stack is not thread safe!
type Stack struct {
    top  *item
    size int
}
// Basic stack methods...
```

The problem is that when I store my Huffman tree structs in the stack I can't use any of the fields of the Huffman tree such as left/right child.

```
package huffmantree

type HuffmanTree struct {
    freq   int
    value  byte
    isLeaf bool
    left   *HuffmanTree
    right  *HuffmanTree
    code   []bool
    depth  int
}
```

How am I supposed to implement a stack in Go which will correctly store structs and allow access to their fields?

Edit:
I tried replacing the `interface {}` part with `huffmantree.HuffmanTree` (huffmantree struct) and got this error message:

```
can't load package: import cycle not allowed
package github.com/inondle/huffman/util
    imports github.com/inondle/huffman/huffmantree
    imports github.com/inondle/huffman/util
import cycle not allowed
```

My guess would be that the huffmantree class imports the util package and the stack has to import the huffmantree package so there is some sort of conflict? Anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: By not using the empty interface{}, but the actual struct. So in your sample: value HuffmanTree.

Comment: A generic version in go is not possible.

Comment: @0x434D53 I tried replacing the interface{} with my huffmantree struct but it caused an error which said `can't load package: import cycle not allowed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way in go to implement a stack is simply to use a slice.

```
stack := []*HuffmanTree{}
```

You can push to the stack using `append`, and pop by writing:

```
v, stack := stack[len(stack)-1], stack[:len(stack)-1]
```

You could encapsulate it into its own type if you prefer, but a slice is easier to understand.

```
type Stack []*HuffmanTree{}

func NewStack() *Stack {
    var s []*HuffmanTree
    return (*Stack)(&s)
}

func (s *Stack) Pop() *HuffmanTree {
   if len(*s) == 0 {
      return nil
    }
    v = (*s)[len(*s)-1]
    *s = (*s)[:len(*s)-1]
    return v
}

func (s *Stack) Push(h *HuffmanTree) {
    *s = append(*s, h)
}
```

As icza observes, if the stacks live longer than the HuffmanTree objects, you may wish to zero the just-popped entry in your stack to allow the garbage collector to collect unreferenced objects.

Comment: I re-implemented the stack encapsulated in its own type but its in the HuffmanTree file along with all the other Tree methods. I did this because If I try to build two packages that import eachother, (huffmantree uses util and util uses huffmantree) then it will give me an import cycle error. It looks pretty odd to go from un-exported stack methods to exported Huffman Tree methods though. Am I doing something wrong or do I have to include my stack code with the huffmantree code?

Comment: @lnondle A package named "util" is a sign that your code organisation can be improved (read: https://blog.golang.org/package-names). I'd expect the stack to live in the same package as your HuffmanTree, possibly with better names (maybe: huffman.Tree, huffman.TreeStack), but not providing a stack and letting callers write their own (since it's trivial) is also tempting. But it's hard to give general advice without knowing your code and use-cases.

Comment: Please note that popping an element from a slice-stack should also fill the space of the popped element with a zero value, because the underlying array will still hold the value and prevent its memory to be reclaimed by the garbage collector. Not zeroing is ok with primitive value types (e.g. `int`) but not ok with pointers , maps, slices or structs which also have pointer fields etc.

Comment: @icza true. I added a comment.